# How to filter out similar records groups that vary by one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sort out some mixed legacy data, and while there is supposed to be a single combination of category_id, item_number, and price -- there is often a duplicate grouping that has a previous set of prices.

Is there a recommended way to query this table, to eliminate the records associated with the prices that are lowest?  Additionally, this is flat CSV data, so the auto-id can be removed if it makes the update easier.

Additionally, there are many more fields in this table which I need to preserve, but are common to either version of the data.

```
+------+-------------+-------------+-------+
|  id  | category_id | item_number | price |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 2971 |       45567 |     5904180 | 2.76  |
| 2977 |       45567 |     5906201 | 2.76  |
| 2980 |       45567 |     5909486 | 2.76  |
| 2981 |       45567 |     5909494 | 2.76  |
| 2982 |       45567 |     5901111 | 2.76  |
| 2983 |       45567 |     5901137 | 2.76  |
| 2984 |       45567 |     5901152 | 2.76  |
| 2987 |       45567 |     5904180 | 8.07  |
| 2993 |       45567 |     5906201 | 8.07  |
| 2996 |       45567 |     5909486 | 8.07  |
| 2997 |       45567 |     5909494 | 8.07  |
| 2998 |       45567 |     5901111 | 8.07  |
| 2999 |       45567 |     5901137 | 8.07  |
| 3000 |       45567 |     5901152 | 8.07  |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete all but the highest prices, you can do:

```
delete tt
    from thistable tt join
         (select tt.category_id, tt.item_number, max(price) as maxprice
          from thistable tt
          group by tt.category_id, tt.item_number
         ) ci
         on tt.category_id = ci.category_id and tt.item_number = ci.item_number and
            tt.price < ci.maxprice;
```

If you really only want to keep the highest id and not the highest price, the use `id` instead of `price` (don't prices ever go down?).

Comment: thank you very much.  This is historical data snapshot, so we are just doing some auditing on it.  I'll give your recommendation a try!